# Is the "address" HTML tag still used?

Tags: html, web-standards

I'm not seeing the usage of address tag around. Is it still relevant using address tag these days? Any proposal to deprecate this arise ever?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's still there in the upcoming [HTML5 spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-address-element):

> The `address` element represents the contact information for its nearest article or body element ancestor. If that is the `body` element, then the contact information applies to the document as a whole.
>   ...
>   The `address` element must not be used to represent arbitrary addresses (e.g. postal addresses), unless those addresses are in fact the relevant contact information. (The `p` element is the appropriate element for marking up postal addresses in general.)
>   The `address` element must not contain information other than contact information.

You're right, it isn't used often, but it should be. I think earlier versions of IE had problems styling it so perhaps that's why it never took off?

Comment: IE7 still always tries to style it as italic, and you have to explicitly put an address { font-style: normal; } in your CSS.

Comment: IE has never had any problems with the address element. It has been around since the original HTML spec and supported by IE since the beginning. As for styling it in italics, isn't that what *every* browser does by default?